# How to use Session on Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I do not know how to use Session on Google app engine.
Please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: Improve your question with other details like, for example, which platform you are using.

Comment: [Edit this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4792334/edit) if you need to add more details.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about request.getSession() in the Java Servlet API?  You have to [enable sessions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions) before that will work. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134800/google-appengine-session-example) for more info on using HttpSession. By the way, you should probably tag your questions with the App Engine variant you're using (java or python).

Answer (score 1):

App Engine includes an implementation of sessions, using the servlet session interface. The implementation stores session data in the App Engine datastore for persistence, and also uses memcache for speed. As with most other servlet containers, the session attributes that are set with session.setAttribute() during the request are persisted at the end of the request.

This feature is off by default. To turn it on, add the following to appengine-web.xml:

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
```